# Static outgoing IP in Kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, amazon-rds, google-kubernetes-engine

I run a k8s cluster in google cloud (GKE) and a MySQL server in aws (RDS). Pods need to connect to RDS which only allows connections from certain IP. How can I configure outgoing traffic to have a static IP?

Comment: Say your code was running on a separate VM without k8s. What would you have done to configure RDS to accept connections?

Comment: I'll add NAT server which has a global IP and configure other servers (say web servers) to connect to the internet via the NAT.

Comment: Hm..I've never used this before, but it seems to me that if you had a web server running on a VM that connects to RDS, RDS would see the incoming connection from the VM's public IP. Which means that you can either have a "proxy" server running on a specific node on your cluster through which your webservers connect to RDS (you can now use that node's public IP) or you can whitelist all the IPs of all the nodes in your cluster for RDS. Does that make sense?

Comment: It might also just be simpler to go to the Security Group settings and allow connections to RDS from anywhere instead of just one IP.

Comment: About whitelisting all the node IPs in the cluster, it's one way but doesn't seem optimal because odes change dynamically. About security group, k8s cluster runs on GCP and MySQL runs on AWS, so I'm not sure if it works.

Comment: Hm..So, you have to have one particular IP which is not changing, through which your connections go. Then there is no option but to proxy all your requests through a service which is on that IP. That means that you can create a proxy service, tie it to a specific node using nodeSelectors in k8s and then whitelist that node's IP. You can reserve an external IP of that node to ensure that even if you destroy  that node, you can bring up a new node with the same IP. In fact, you can extend this idea to multiple nodes. Reserve a set of IPs, assign those public IPs and so on.

Comment: That way, we must ensure that one of the nodes has a certain IP, which seems difficult (what should we do when the size of node decreased and a node having the IP is killed?). It might be simpler to have a proxy server out side of the k8s cluster.

Comment: I have a similar need for my k8s cluster in GKE that needs to access an external provider where I should whitelist IPs. Did you end up with a solution then?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reserve a range of static IPs for Kubernetes pods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46687208/reserve-a-range-of-static-ips-for-kubernetes-pods)

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem to connect to a sftp server from a Pod.
To solve this, first you need to create an external IP address:

```
gcloud compute addresses create {{ EXT_ADDRESS_NAME }} --region {{ REGION }}
```

Then, I suppose that your pod is assigned to your default-pool node cluster.
Extract your default-pool node name:

```
gcloud compute instances list | awk '{ print $1 }' | grep default-pool
```

Erase default external ip of the vm instance:

```
gcloud compute instances delete-access-config {{ VM_DEFAULT-POOL_INSTANCE }} --access-config-name external-nat
```

Add your external static ip created before:

```
gcloud compute instances add-access-config {{ VM_DEFAULT-POOL_INSTANCE }} --access-config-name external-nat --address {{ EXT_ADDRESS_IP }}
```

If your Pod is not attached to the default-pool node, don't forget to select it with a nodeSelector:

```
nodeSelector:
    cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool: {{ NODE_NAME }}
```

Comment: For some reason the `add-access-config` command requires the `zone` and `network-interface` parameters. Other then that it worked like a charm.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! One thing is not very clear for me. Do pods always run on only one node with this approach?

Comment: It's a basic config, with the default-pool. In this case it's running with one pod on only one node.

Comment: What we wanted to accomplish was running multiple pods across multiple nodes. We accomplished this using NAT gateway and gcp's routing rules.

Comment: @Shouichi are there not any additional transfer overhead costs involved in this?

Answer (score 8):

I made some research and I found a couple of things.

The thing we are looking for is called "egress IPs" or NAT-as-a-Service and they are both not yet available in GKE.

In any case we have two different options:

1. create a NAT Gateway VM which acts as an egress proxy. Here is a nice article talking about that ([google cloud NAT gateway](https://docs.tenable.com/pvs/deployment/Content/GoogleCloudInstructionsNatGateway.htm))
2. assign static IPs to container cluster VM instances

Hope it helps!

Comment: Just to be sure here, wouldn't this (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/source-ip/) take care of the described needs?

Comment: mmhh don't think so @Zed_Blade: service is always a matter of requests coming from outside and served from pods .. The issue on the other hand here is NAT for outsource traffic.

Comment: Same discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kubernetes-users/zNytc8GVB5s) . The [NAT gateway](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#natgateway) seems the way to go for now.

Comment: Updated google instructions GCE/K8s: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/using-a-nat-gateway-with-kubernetes-engine

Answer (score 5):

I know this is really old, but for me the solution is to create a private kubernetes cluster in google cloud. If the cluster is private then the nodes won't have any external ips. If the nodes don't have external ip's and we have a cloud nat, then all the out going traffic will have the same ip as cloud nat ip. All of this can be done through google cloud console.

I found this article to be informative on creating private cluster.
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters

If the cluster is private and you need to access it from some remote area, use this command:

> gcloud container clusters update {cluster_name}  --enable-master-authorized-networks   --master-authorized-networks {CIDR notation of your ip}

NOTE: Create the cloud nat in the same region as the the kubernetes cluster. Also when creating the cloud nat, make sure you select 'manual' option for NAT ip addresses, then select one static ip you have. Leave the rest of the configuration to default unless you know what you're doing.

After everything is setup, kubectl exec to any of your pod running in any node. Use dig command to check your outgoing ip.

> dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com

It should be the same as the cloud nat ip.

Answer (score 1):

You can use kubeip, a pod that for every new node will assign an ip address from a predefined pool.