# Reserve a range of static IPs for Kubernetes pods

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am attempting to build a Kubernetes cluster on Google Container Engine where its pods do requests to the internet (incoming or egress traffic). These outgoing connections must be limited to a static IP or limited to a range of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The external IP address is the IP address of the node machines in the GKE cluster. You can specify static IP address to these node vms from the VPC Network => External IP addresses.

A more complex option would be to create a [NAT gateway](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpc/special-configurations#natgateway) on a separate VM and then route all the traffic from Kubernetes nodes through it.

Comment: The problem with this approach is it won't work with autoscaling pools.

Answer (score 0):

You can opt to https://github.com/doitintl/kubeIP and avoid configuring with NAT